# How to zoom and scroll in QGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

In a project where I use QGLWidget to create my own image viewer, I'm trying to add zooming and scrolling feature in displaying large images but I get a problem where the image is cut and cannot be wider than it's original size or the panel size.

Here i set up the viewport and glScalef. In implementing scrolling, I subclass QAbstractScrollArea and pass the coordinate of scrollbars into a variable.

```
// scrollOffset has the coordinates of horizontal and vertical scrollbars
// this->width() and this->height() are panel size
glViewport(0 - scrollOffset.x(), 0 + scrollOffset.y(), this->width(),  this->height());
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0, this->width(),  this->height(),  0);  // flip the y axis
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// if zoomFactor value is 1.0 means no zooming
glScalef(zoomFactor, zoomFactor, 1.0);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Render the image:

```
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId );
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, tex.width(), tex.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bits());    
glBegin(GL_QUADS);    
// text coords are flipped in y axis
// width and height are image's original size
glTexCoord2d(0,1); glVertex3d(0,     0,      0);
glTexCoord2d(1,1); glVertex3d(width, 0,      0);
glTexCoord2d(1,0); glVertex3d(width, height, 0);
glTexCoord2d(0,0); glVertex3d(0,     height, 0);    
glEnd();
```

in image below, i scroll down the image but the displayed image cannot be taller than the panel's height

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not abuse glViewport for zooming. The viewport is used to set, to which part of the (visible) window NDC coordinates are mapped after projection. Usually you set glViewport to the size of the window you're drawing to.

Any zooming and scrolling should be done by adjustment of the projection matrix, by adjusting the left, right, bottom and top limits to what's to be shown.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, even though my scrolling code is not that elegant it works just fine, actually I use glviewport only for scrolling and the zooming feature uses glScalef. The problem right now glScalef doesn't work as expected